# cant understand the concept of the many projects in one solution in vs2010

Tags: visual-studio

I seem having difficulty in understanding the reason behind the need of having many projects inside one solution (in my case visual studio 2010 with c#).

The only use that comes to mind is if I am creating a new classes I can test them in a console application first, then add another project to the solution to use these classes with the project that I want.

kindly guide me to the correct way, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 3 main reasons that immediately come to mind for splitting your solution into multiple projects: Reuse, Encapsulation, and Project-specific settings.

1. *Reuse*
   You may have a Utilities project that is shared between more than one solution. You may also have data access and business rules that are defined in class libraries, but are shared between multiple UI projects, such as having a business application that has a web interface, a desktop interface, and web services. They all need to share the same logic and data model, so you wouldn't want to replicate it in each solution separately.
2. *Encapsulation*
   Another reason is to achieve encapsulation, one of the main principles of OOP. Your classes may have internal methods and properties (or the classes themselves may even be defined as internal), which makes them only visible to other classes in the same project. If it's there to achieve a specific purpose but not something that should be accessible to all, by splitting your classes across separate projects you can make those properties, methods, and classes visible to your classes, but hidden outside the scope of your project.
3. *Project-specific settings*
   There are certain project types that behave completely differently from one another. A Web Project is different from a Windows Forms app, which is completely different than a WPF app. This kind of goes along with #1 and trying to achieve code reuse; since you can't have a single project that is a website *AND* a Windows Forms app *AND* a WPF app, you create each UI as its own project and put as much logic as possible into a separate project that can be shared between all of the UI projects.

Answer (score 3):

A typical project might have a UI, a data layer, a services layer, and a domain layer, as well as some tests.  A typical arrangement would be for each of these to exist as their own project file.  The solution would contain all of these projects so that you can make modifications and debug different parts of the app at once.

If you're just starting out, you probably cram all of this stuff into one project.  That's fine for learning, but is an absolute mess for maintainability and reusability.

Comment: Also, generally, the relationship between solutions and projects is not 1-to-many. Each project can be re-used into another solution (aka a different project). This is quite common if that project is a library for example.

Answer (score 0):

A couple possible reasons off the top of my head:

- a project may be useful in more than one solution
- simple organization utility - just like you might have classes in separate files even though a single source file can hold multiple classes just fine.